# Can git archive include the directory that the .git project lives in?

Tags: git, git-archive

Can git archive include the directory that the .git project lives in?

For example, let's say my directory structure is like this:

```
-- /my-project-dir
----- /.git
----- /css
----- index.html
----- scripts.js
```

By default, when I do a git archive, I end up with a ZIP file like so:

```
-- my-project-dir.zip
----- /css
----- index.html
----- scripts.js
```

I'm wondering if there is a way that the `archive` command can include the parent directory as well, for example:

```
-- my-project-dir.zip
----- /my-project-dir
-------- /css
-------- index.html
-------- scripts.js
```

Comment: I use `git bundle` this is just a file which you can then clone from.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `--prefix` option:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ ls -A
bar  .git
$ git archive --prefix foo/ -o foo.tar master
$ tar tf foo.tar
foo/
foo/bar
```

Be careful to include the trailing slash in `foo/`, otherwise you end up with the prefix prepended to each filename!